# angular2 @input not working

Tags: angular, components

I'm gonna pass a value into my custom component but it shows me an error in console

> Can't bind to 'isFavorite' since it isn't a known native property

here is my code:

**favorite.component.ts**

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core'
@Component ({
    selector:'favorite',
    template:`
    <i class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    `
})
export class FavoriteComponent{
    @Input() isFavorite = false;
    onClick(){
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {FavoriteComponent} from './favorite.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <favorite [isFavorite]="true"></favorite>
    `,
   directives: [FavoriteComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**UPDATE:** the above code is better way to achieve this functionality and you can fix the problem by passing the name to @input() -> `@Input('isFavorite') isFavorite = false;`

---

### different way but the same result

i also tried below code but it shows me the same error!

**favorite.component.ts**

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core'
@Component ({
    selector:'favorite',
    template:`
    <i class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    `,
    inputs: ['isFavorite:is-favorite']
})
export class FavoriteComponent{
    @Input('is-favorite') isFavorite = false;
    onClick(){
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {FavoriteComponent} from './favorite.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <favorite is-favorite="true"></favorite>
    `,
   directives: [FavoriteComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Does your component is applied without the input?

Comment: Have you tried without `inputs: ['isFavorite:is-favorite']`?

Comment: What version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer yes, you can see in my question

Comment: "UPDATE: this way is better to achieve this functionality and you can fix the problem by passing the name to @input() -> @Input('isFavorite') isFavorite = false;" better than what? Didn't you see my answer. There is no need to pass `'isFavorite'` if it is the same as the name of the property. The name of the property is the default value if you just use `@Input() isFavorite`.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbaue i have tried `@Input() isFavorite` before in my code(as you can see in my question) but it doesn't work! maybe it depends on angular version!

Comment: You need to have quite an old version (alpha.x) for this not to work. I use Angular since the first beta and have never seen an issue with this. Do you still have the `inputs: [...]` in the `@Component(...)` decorator?

Comment: no, but it works when i change my code to this `@Input('isFavorite') isFavorite = false;`    thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use `inputs: [...]` **OR** `@Input(...)` but not both at the same time:

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core'
@Component ({
    selector:'favorite',
    template:`
    <i class="glyphicon"
    [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite"
    [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    `,
    // inputs: ['isFavorite:is-favorite']
})
export class FavoriteComponent{
    @Input('is-favorite') isFavorite = false;
    onClick(){
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

The error messages comes from

```
<favorite [isFavorite]="true"></favorite>
```

If you use

```
inputs: ['isFavorite:is-favorite']
```

or

```
@Input('is-favorite') isFavorite = false;
```

it means the property is named `is-favorite` but the value is assigned to the class field `isFavorite`.

If you want to use it like

```
<favorite [isFavorite]="true"></favorite>
```

define it like

```
inputs: ['isFavorite']
```

or

```
@Input() isFavorite = false;
```

Comment: `isFavorite` is always false (uses default class field) but i want to make it true

Comment: How do you want to use it? `is-favorite="..."` or `isFavorite="..."`?

Comment: If you want to assign the value `true` instead of the string `'true'`, then use `[isFavorite]="true"`

Comment: i'm using `@Input() isFavorite = false;` and `<favorite [isFavorite]="true"></favorite>` but it doesn't work!

Comment: Did you check my plunker? I think this is what you want.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried your plnkr. But  many 404 errors in chrome debugging tools

Comment: I updated the plunker to a recent Angular version but it still causes errors. https://plnkr.co/edit/iXa3PGMjDPx8FjFYyCqt?p=preview I'm pretty sure it's not because of the code it contains.